# Is there a Krull-Schmidt theorem for Z-algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

If $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field, then, by Krull-Schmidt, every finitely generated $A$-module

1. can be decomposed into a (finite) direct sum of indecomposable submodules
2. the decomposition is unique up to isomorphism.

Now suppose $A$ is a torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra of finite $\mathbb{Z}$-rank.

**Q1:** Is there a Krull-Schmidt theorem for finitely generated $A$-modules ?

To be more precise: By induction on the $\mathbb{Z}$-rank, it follows that every finitely generated torsion-free module is a direct sum of indecomposables. So 1.  holds in this context.

**Q2:** Do all such decompositions into indecomposables have the same number of summands ?

N.b.: By "torsion-fre" I mean torsion-free as abelian group and the $\mathbb{Z}$-rank is just the rank of the underlying free abelian group.

Answer (score 3):

Generally 2. does not hold, i.e. the Krull-Schmidt Theorem does not hold for f.g. $A$-modules.

Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, where $\zeta_{23} \in \mathbb{C}$ is a 23rd root of 1.  The projective module group $K_0(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}])$ is the same as the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$, which is not the trivial group.  Thus, there are two projective (and hence torsion-free) $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ which are not free, but whose direct sum is free.

This only shows the failure of 2.  I do not have an example which shows the answer to Q2 is no.

Perhaps relevant: there is a body of work on torsion-free Krull-Schmidt Theorems for integral group rings.  Example with some references: "On the Krull-Schmidt-Azumaya Theorem for Integral Group Rings", by Peter Hindman, Lee Klingler and Charles Odenthal.

Also perhaps relevant, there is a Krull-Schmidt Theorem for algebras over the p-adic integers.